# IndexError: list index out of range for the caesar cipher

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am making a Caesar cipher, and I get an out of index error when i run the code. It works and encrypts the message when it's a few letters, but when I enter in more than ten words it gives me an index error.

```
shift_key = int(raw_input("Enter in your key shift: 1-9\n>>> "))

alphabet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
encrypted_alphabet = []
encrypted_message = ''

for i in alphabet[shift_key:]:
    encrypted_alphabet.append(i)

input = raw_input("Enter text to be decoded\n>>> ").upper()
input = input.split()

for i in input:
    for j in i:
        index = alphabet.index(j)
        encrypted_message += encrypted_alphabet[index]
    encrypted_message += ' '
print encrypted_message
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: If you `import string`, you could replace your long `alphabet` list with `string.ascii_uppercase`

Comment: Hint hint... use modulus :) It'll make it "wrap around" and start from zero in the array. Single character example: `encrypted_char = alphabet[(alphabet.index(plain_char) + shift_value) % len(alphabet)]`. Alphabet could be `alphabet = [chr(x) for x in range(65,91)]`

Comment: Thanks for the explaining the additional methods of creating an alphabet. Both work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
for i in alphabet[shift_key:]:
    encrypted_alphabet.append(i)
```

Notice that doing `alphabet[shift_key:]` *slices* the list `alphabet` to only take those elements starting from `shift_key`.

In other words, if `shift_key` is 25, for example, then `alphabet[shift_key:]` returns just `['Y','Z']`. Since you're appending these to `encrypted_alphabet`, `encrypted_alphabet` then becomes just `['Y','Z']`. But what you want is also the *rest* of the alphabet appended to the end of `encrypted_alphabet`.

Simply put, the *lengths* of your `encrypted_alphabet` and `alphabet` mismatch.

You can correct it this very simply by

```
for i in alphabet[shift_key:] + alphabet[:shift_key]:
    encrypted_alphabet.append(i)
```

or (even more simply)

```
encrypted_alphabet = alphabet[shift_key:] + alphabet[:shift_key]
```

---

If you want to know the *right* way to do this, however, use the inbuilt string method [`maketrans`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm) instead, which is far simpler:

```
import string

shift_key = int(raw_input("Enter in your key shift: 1-9\n>>> "))

alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
encrypted_alphabet = alphabet[shift_key:] + alphabet[:shift_key]
caesar = string.maketrans(alphabet,encrypted_alphabet)
input = raw_input("Enter text to be decoded\n>>> ").upper()

print(input.translate(caesar))
```

**Quick explanation**

As the code indicates, `maketrans` creates a *translation table* between two strings, mapping each character in the first to the other. You can then feed this translation table into the `.translate()` method that every string has.

Comment: `maktrans` -> `maketrans` Good way of doing it btw.

Comment: @jDo Thanks, fixing :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Could you please ELI5 on what maketrans does real quick?

Comment: @avbirm Edited with a description of `maketrans` anyway.